# Default http/admin port in dropwizard project

Tags: java, port, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard project and I have maintained a config.yml file at the ROOT of the project (basically at the same level as pom.xml). Here I have specified the HTTP port to be used as follows:

```
http:
    port:9090
    adminPort:9091
```

I have the following code in my TestService.java file

```
public class TestService extends Service<TestConfiguration> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<TestConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.setName("test");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(TestConfiguration config, Environment env) throws Exception {
        // initialize some resources here..
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestService().run(new String[] { "server" });
    }

}
```

I expect the config.yml file to be used to determine the HTTP port. However the app always seems to start with the default ports 8080 and 8081. Also note that I am running this from eclipse.

Any insights as to what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: What version of dropwizard are you using?

Comment: Currently using the version 0.6.2

Comment: What are your run configurations? Are you running "server /path/to/yaml"?

Comment: I am not passing any values via the run configurations. I am just executing the main() method of the Service show above. There I am passing the server as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your service as follows:

Rewrite your main method into:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestService().run(args);
}
```

Then in eclipse go to Run --> Run configurations...., create a new run configuration for your class, go to `arguments` and add "server path/to/config.yml" in "program arguments". If you put it in the root directory, it would be "server config.yml"

I believe you are not passing the location/name of the `.yml` file and thus your configurations are not being loaded. Another solution is to just add the location of your config file to the array you're passing into run ;)

Comment: Had tried it before, looks like the issue was that my yml file was not well formed :). Now it works !!